# In Parity, what is the equivalent RPC call to geth's txpool_content?

Tags: parity, pending-transactions, txpool

There are several useful [txpool queries](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#txpool) in geth: `txpool_content`, `txpool_inspect` and `txpool_status`. Since these are not part of the general standard, Parity likely has some other name for the same mechanism.

Ideally, I would get a list of transaction details or hashes that are pending for a supplied account. Although, geth doesn't have an option to filter the results by account, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 8):

The closest I was able to find is [`parity_pendingTransactions`](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-parity-module#parity_pendingtransactions) and [`parity_pendingTransactionsStats`](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-parity-module#parity_pendingtransactionsstats).

`parity_pendingTransactions` is very similar to geth's `txpool_content`, and gets the job done.

---

*Update*: Since I was specifically looking for transactions sent from a specific account, this new method works even better: [`parity_localTransactions`](https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-parity-module#parity_localtransactions)

It only returns the locally-generated transactions. Note that it **also lists mined transactions** sent locally, so if you only want pending transactions, you'll have to filter them out afterward, using the status field. An example query/response:

```
curl --data '{"method":"parity_localTransactions","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545
{
  "id": 1,
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": {
    "0x09e64eb1ae32bb9ac415ce4ddb3dbad860af72d9377bb5f073c9628ab413c532": {
      "status": "mined",
      "transaction": {
        "from": "0x00a329c0648769a73afac7f9381e08fb43dbea72",
        "to": "0x00a289b43e1e4825dbedf2a78ba60a640634dc40",
        "value": "0xfffff",
        "blockHash": null,
        "blockNumber": null,
        "creates": null,
        "gas": "0xe57e0",
        "gasPrice": "0x2d20cff33",
        "hash": "0x09e64eb1ae32bb9ac415ce4ddb3dbad860af72d9377bb5f073c9628ab413c532",
        "input": "0x",
        "condition": {
          "block": 1
        },
        "networkId": null,
        "nonce": "0x0",
        "publicKey": "0x3fa8c08c65a83f6b4ea3e04e1cc70cbe3cd391499e3e05ab7dedf28aff9afc538200ff93e3f2b2cb5029f03c7ebee820d63a4c5a9541c83acebe293f54cacf0e",
        "raw": "0xf868808502d20cff33830e57e09400a289b43e1e4825dbedf2a78ba60a640634dc40830fffff801ca034c333b0b91cd832a3414d628e3fea29a00055cebf5ba59f7038c188404c0cf3a0524fd9b35be170439b5ffe89694ae0cfc553cb49d1d8b643239e353351531532",
        "standardV": "0x1",
        "v": "0x1c",
        "r": "0x34c333b0b91cd832a3414d628e3fea29a00055cebf5ba59f7038c188404c0cf3",
        "s": "0x524fd9b35be170439b5ffe89694ae0cfc553cb49d1d8b643239e353351531532",
        "transactionIndex": null
      }
    },
    "0x...": { ... }
  }
}
```

Comment: An approach to filtering out already-mined local transactions is finding an intersection of the local and pending transactions. This does require two queries instead of one.

Answer (score -1):

```
curl --data '{"method":"parity_pendingTransactions","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://sokol.poa.network
```

This is how I see all pending tx in particular node
https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-parity-module#parity_pendingtransactions

Comment: The documentation isn t up to date and this method now require parameters.